# Is dating other PhD students a terrible idea if I want to stay in academia longterm?

Tags: phd, academic-life, two-body-problem

In his book “Good work if you can get it: How to succeed in academia”, Jason Brennan advises aspiring academics against dating other PhD students while on graduate school.
Of course, I know that everyone is free to love anyone.
I’m not in a situation where I am deciding whether to date a particular PhD student or not. But there are things that I could do to increase the possibility of it happening (eg online dating, asking friends if they know someone who might be a good fit, etc).

Having read about the two-body problem that many academics face, I wonder what dating strategy (eg waiting until having a permanent position to date, dating someone with a job outside of academia, etc) I should have if I want to maximise my chances of landing a permanent academic job while having a SO (which I don’t currently have).

Note: I’m a first year PhD student at a top-3 university in the world for my field. My funding is the most prestigious scholarship available in my university for PhD students. So I have reasons to believe that my chances of landing an academic job are significantly higher than for an average PhD student. Might spousal-hires be a possibility longterm? Or dating another superstar PhD student to increase the odds of both getting a postdocs/jobs at the same universities.

Comment: You can still have a 'two-body problem' with a partner who isn't an academic. For example, they may need to be in a particular city for their career or family reasons, or perhaps they need to be in a major city while you get a job offer in a rural campus university.  It's hard enough to find a partner you're compatible with, I wouldn't add their career plans as a criteria.

Comment: Dating another academic might even make things easier, as they also tend to be open to moving around, and many universities have dual career programs. Or, spouses (academics or not) may want to move elsewhere for their own, personal reasons. This really depends a too much on the individuals involved. If each prioritizes the career over the relationship (like you seem to do: "maximize chances (...) while (...)") it will be tough anyway.

Comment: Despite dual-career programs, it's worth considering that dating an academic in the same field/department can be more problematic than an academic in a different one. This is because break-ups and divorces happen, and a department might be reluctant to potentially have to deal with those.

Comment: @lighthouse keeper Thanks for the comment. Yes, I’m definitely not particularly interested in dating people in my own field and especially not from my own department.

Comment: Your chances of finding a suitable partner in a demanding and time-consuming job are lower than usual anyway, if that's a priority at all, do not put additional constraints on it.

Comment: Note, that, even if your partner is not in the same field, there is always the possibility of additional competitiveness and both partners have to be very tolerant of the other partner potentially being more successful than themselves.

Comment: One more comment about the last paragraph: While it may be correct that being a PhD student at a top university increases your chances on the job market, it doesn't render you a *superstar* - the only thing that does is a superstar track record.

Comment: @lighthousekeeper And also, dating someone because they are a superstar is probably as effective at finding the right person as dating them because they make the most money or because they are a famous film actor/tress. In short, not a good idea.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs I dunno. If they're both highly academically-focused and driven individuals, that could act as a point of similarity between them.

Comment: @nick012000 Yes, that works until one of them gets in crisis (which happens in all but the lucky few individuals). Or somehow other cracks appear. It's not a good criterion. Now, I am not saying that driven individuals cannot find common ground, but there needs to be a common ground that is not the drive - the one exception is if they complement each other, in other words, if they need each other's contribution - that can work. Apart from that situation, drive on its own is simply not a good criterion.

Comment: Voting to close, this question is too opinion based

Comment: @lighthousekeeper Thanks for all the comments. Re the superstar comment, I used it as short for “someone academically driven/focused” etc rather than trying to say that I am a superstar (but I see how your interpretation is reasonable from what I wrote)

Comment: @anonymous If you meet someone with whom there's mutual interest, I'd say go for it. If you do go on to an academic career, it is probably 7-8 years or more until you are in a permanent position. Moreover, dating might not be easy then, especially if you end up in an isolated location. Very best of luck to you.

Comment: *"I’m a [...] PhD student at a top-3 university"*, *"another superstar PhD student"*, *"I wonder what dating strategy"*: I don't intend to be rude, but you seem to have a rather narrow view on how professional success works; and - even more importantly - you are even extrapolating this view to your private life...

Comment: @jochenglueck Sorry to have given the wrong impression. As for being una top-3 university that’s a fact (if you believe in ranks at least) and I’m not saying it to show off, rather to avoid answers of the sort “your chances of landing an academic job are incredibly low anyway”. Re the superstar use, I addressed that in a previous question. Finally, re “dating strategy”, look, I’m not trying to apply any algorithm or any of that stuff, but, as mentioned in the question, there are things I can do (trying to meet many grad students, dating apps, trying to meet people outside of academia, etc)

Comment: @anonymous Unfortunately, your chances of landing an academic job are incredibly low anyway.

Comment: @BryanKrause That's as truthful as to say "your chances of finding a lasting relationship are very low these days"; it will not keep people from trying (and also should not do so), so I am not sure what the use of it is.

Comment: @CaptainEmacs Far more people will have a lasting relationship than graduate students will get permanent faculty positions, and if you fail at the former which almost everyone does several times you get to try again; for the latter, there is little opportunity past a certain point. The meaning of my comment was that OP seems to think that by being a "superstar" in a top 3 school their academic career future is a solid bet such that answers should not address that a permanent academic career is not a solid bet for anyone: neither them nor their potential grad student dating partners.

Comment: @anonymous: Thanks for your response! Hmm, I think that you might have misinterpreted my comment. My point was not whether I agree or disagree with any of the specific statements I quoted, but that many of your statements (the three I picked out are just examples) suggest the following: You seem to believe that relations between cause and effect are often quite straightforward, and rather easy to isolate, to describe and to influence. To be honest, the way you phrased your post immediately reminded me of the notion [Illusion of control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusion_of_control).

Comment: Of course, you're actions do have considerable influence on your future welfare, but this is often a very subtle and long-term process. Basing decisions (career or personal) on ideas like "a PhD from a top university strongly increases my chances to land a permanent academic position" or "dating other PhD students is unwise due to a potential two-body problem" heavily overestimates the control that such kind of criteria give you in the long run, while it heavily underestimates the influence of other more subtle but highly relevant factors.

Comment: @jochenglueck thanks for the clarification and for your new comment. It may be very true that I’m overestimating the effects of my actions. A PhD from a top uni does increase my chances to some level, but I don’t know how _strongly_ (that is subjective, and Im not giving any actual probabilities here). (I know that publishing etc is very important too as well as luck). And regarding the dating statement, I don’t how negative it is in the longterm to date other grad students, but that’s the very point of my question (I’m asking because I’ve read it and I want to know what others think about it)

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase the question in terms of probabilities or simply ask for personal experiences with two-body problems (I’ve read a few posts about it in this site, but I want to avoid selection bias as much as possible)

Answer (score 1):

If that book gives this kind of advice, it seems a really good book.
To prevent people from enjoying life and becoming unempathic academics, at best ready to get and facilitate burn-outs through their careers, treating their professional lives as a bubble completely split from their human being existence.

Even the suggestion about not getting involved romantically with someone in your department/research topic, you can find so many couples that split as many couple that navigated their career through that. Sure, you should not be dependent on the relevant other for your career&co., but that is a general advice. You can be working in the same department and being totally independent, as well as working in different sectors (i.e. politics and finance) and having strong, unhealthy, professional bonds.

However, the good news is that if you follow exactly the contrary of that advice, you may discover that having a partner involved in the academy makes much easier to move as a couple, because of the intrinsic instability in the academic career, unless you land a permanent job at a decent institution, where the daul-career programs are a great solution to the two-body problems.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, the author advocates for the free-market of organs, 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvKmmODb7XA
just focusing on one side of efficient allocation of resources.

Comment: Do you mean "not a really good book"?

Comment: @IanSudbery I am thinking that it is one of these great books that deserves reading, because they are very good at concentrating all the "wrong" ideas about a certain set of topics, with the author weights in with his "experience" while contemporary claiming to be bias-free (always, always consider survivorship bias https://xkcd.com/1827/ )

Comment: @EarlGrey I try to subvert this trope. I explicilty explain to my PhD students what the attrition rate is from postgrad to permanent faculty. I explain that I made it, and of course I made it, because you can only be supervised by people that made it. It's the anthropic principle on a down-to-earth scale. It occasionally works.

Answer (score 1):

The book doesn't say you should never date another PhD student or break up with a current significant other if you are dating one. It says that the two body problem is hard to overcome, and so you should all things equal try to date outside the narrow circle of academia.

Comment: but why? all things equal in which sense? why should the 2-body problems be easier in the industry? There are more positions in industry in a single geographic locations than academia positions, but it does not mean that industry positions in different locations can be easily swapped. If that is the line of thinking, it would be much more meaningful to suggest to date inside the circle of very rich people, or suggesting to study medicine because it is the faculty with more chance of employment inside or outside the academia (all things equal, of course)...